# Mount resources within '/api' in addition to their normal route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to be able to mount all of our resources at both their 'natural' route and within '/api'.  Is there an easy way to do this with rails routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting errors like `unitialized constant Api::SomeControllerClass` with the above solution.

I was able to get this to work by doing the following

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  def api_enabled_routes
    resources :foo do
      resources :bar
    end
    <etc>
  end

  api_enabled_routes

  scope '/api' do
    api_enabled_routes
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Create some file like `config/routes/api_routes.rb` and put the routes you want for their "natural" and "`/api`" states. Then load the file into your `config/routes.rb`, once directly into the block, and once within a `namespace` block *(assuming your `Api` is namespaced)*.

```
Your::Application.routes.draw do
  load 'routes/api_routes.rb'

  namespace :api do
    load 'routes/api_routes.rb'
  end

  # ...
end
```